# unable to print text on image

Tags: php, image

I am trying to write text on image and displaying that image on browser. I tried below code but it is not working properly. Below code is showing one empty square (no image). Can anyone tell what's wrong I am doing here.

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('images/travel.jpg');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
$text = "This is a sunset!";
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $text);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in your code is this line

```
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $text);
```

As mentioned in the doc http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php
you have to pass font file path too

So just change the line

```
imagettftext($jpg_image, 15, 0, 15, 15, $white, 'Roboto-Bold.ttf',$text);
```

and put a font file to the folder and it will work.

If you don't want to give the font file replace the line

```
imagettftext($jpg_image, 25, 0, 75, 300, $white, $text);
```

With

```
imagestring($jpg_image,15,15,15,$text,$white);
```

Your code will be

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$jpg_image = imagecreatefromjpeg('https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQf66Ol6NAa6sdNhDJT0z1fVfTmjPjxAHkopPwExZ9AqHSqNzHP');
$white = imagecolorallocate($jpg_image, 255, 255, 255);
$text = "This is a sunset!";
imagestring($jpg_image,15,15,15,$text,$white);
imagejpeg($jpg_image);
imagedestroy($jpg_image);
?>
```

This will work for you

Comment: I replaced imagettftext($jpg_image, 15, 0, 15, 15, $white, 'Roboto-Bold.ttf',$text); with imagestring($jpg_image,15,15,15,$text,$white); but still it is not working. Getting same output.

Comment: You have 'images/travel.jpg' in your folder. I have edited my answer take a look

Comment: Thanks for your help. Above code is working for me. But what should i do if I want to provide an image from images folder?

Comment: Just provide the image path to that folder and it will work. I think you are not giving correct path to the image. As i have tested it and its working fine. If you provide the file structure so that i can check where you are wrong